# ELOGIN Error with Node.js and SQL Server database Connection

Tags: node.js, sql-server, config

I am trying to connect my SQL Database which is in sql server management studio to Node.js. Currently, the connection is being done locally on my machine. This is the error which I keep on getting:

```
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'database access'.
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1051:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1079:18)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2608:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {      
  code: 'ELOGIN',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'database access'.       
      at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:245:19)
      at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Aviation Calc\calc\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
      at Readable.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {    
    code: 'ELOGIN',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
NOT CONNECTED
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

At first I thought that this may be ocurring because I havent enabled windows firewall to allow my port: 1433 but even after doing that I kept on getting the same error message. I also made sure to enable the SQL Server Services in SQL Configuration Manager.

Here is my code:

dbConfig.js

```
const config = {

    // dialect: 'mssql',

    user: 'database access',
    password: 'tronn6215',
    // DESKTOP-NKHJ1GI
    // SQLQuery1.sql
    server: 'DESKTOP-NKHJ1GI',
    database: 'Avtag Data',
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        trustedConnection: false,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    },
    // dynamic_port: 51582 (dynamic port num)
    // port: 50381
    port: 1433

    //have enabled window firewall to allow static port 1433 for connection but still error
    //Now error- code: 'ELOGIN'
    
}

module.exports = config;
```

dbOperation.js

```
const config = require('./dbConfig'),
sql = require('mssql');

const getEntryPoint = async() => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let entry = pool.request().query("SELECT * from ENTRY _POINT1")
        console.log(entry);
        console.log('CONNECTED')
        return entry;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('NOT CONNECTED')

    }
}

module.exports = {
    getEntryPoint
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
dbOperation = require('./dbFiles/dbOperation'),
cors = require('cors');
    
dbOperation.getEntryPoint().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Aside... specify a `port`, or specify an `instanceName`, don't specify both. If you know the `port` use that, which bypasses the whole process of needing to resolve the instance name to a port by way of the SQL Browser service.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server instance's Error Log for information? If the client is actually connecting, but failing to authenticate, you should see Error 18456 events present. Take note of the State number there and compare it against the list of State numbers at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine why the login is failing.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction and I found a solution.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, that qou found a solution, but please let us know what it is.